# How to sort this string and rebuild the same sorted string again

Tags: java, sorting

How can I ***sort*** values in this string based on the integral parts **i.e.**

**Input:**

`[160,190];[650,790];[901,974];[401,540];[60,90];`

**O/p:**

`[60,90];[160,190];[401,540];[650,790];[901,974];`

> Obviously a regular sort must do in this case but I am not sure about
>   where should I **trim** the strings **compare** and **rebuild** the exact string
>   with optimized approach.

Comment: Split on ";"  ,  add ";" to end of all split cells, sort it!!

Comment: What if the ranges overlap? What if two numbers appear twice? Can you clearly define the sort criteria? The answer now would _sort_ `[1,4];[2,3]` to `[1,2];[3,4]`...

Comment: I don't understand the reason for downvote on a question like this. lame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each `[]` specifies a unique range of values, you can extract all numbers, sort them and then construct the resultant string back by grouping two elements in each `[]`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
Set<Integer> numbers = new TreeSet<>();

while(matcher.find()) {
    numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)));
}
```

Next step would be to iterate over `numbers` and use the current and next index to form the resultant string.

An even better approach is to split the string on `;` and use [@Sergey N Lukin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19905628/858366)'s Comparator to sort the values

```
    String s = "[160,190];[650,790];[901,974];[401,540];[60,90];";
    String[] values = s.split(";");
    Set<String> sortedValues = new TreeSet<>(new TokensComparator());
    sortedValues.addAll(Arrays.asList(values));
```

Eventually, join the set's elements with a semi-colon(`;`) using a loop or Google Guava's `Joiner`

```
Joiner.on(';').join(sortedValues);
```

Comment: I have used this approach and have posted complete working code as an answer also.

Comment: Using a Set will cause you big problem, because it will delete duplicate values.

Comment: @jlordo By "If each cell `[]` specifies a unique range of values", I mean that the values in a range are never repeated in other ranges, which also means that the string doesn't contain duplicate range elements. You should've read the first line before down-voting.

Answer (score 1):

I'd implement the [Comparator interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html); a class holding both values of a pair and then:

- parse the string using ';' as delimeter and put it in holder class
- put all of the holder objects into a List
- sort the list using the implemented comparator

Answer (score 1):

Using Guava instead of reimplementing most of the necessary steps.
The first part, parsing the string and converting it to a list of integers will be much nicer, once Lambda expressions can be used.

```
import static com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.anyOf;
import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList;
import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.transform;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;

public class StrangeSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "[160,190];[650,790];[901,974];[401,540];[60,90]";
        Splitter splitter = Splitter.on(anyOf("[],;")).omitEmptyStrings();
        // This will be so much nicer with Lambda Expressions
        List<Integer> list = newArrayList(transform(newArrayList(splitter.split(input)),
            new Function<String, Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer apply(String arg0) {
                    return Integer.valueOf(arg0);
                }}));
        // Sort the list
        Collections.sort(list);
        // Print the list
        String output = Joiner.on(';').join(Iterables.partition(list, 2));
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

If you need to get rid of the whitespace in the output, you can print `output.replaceAll(" ", "");`

Comment: This wouldn't work if the string contains duplicate ranges. For e.g., by putting a duplicate range, say, `[70,80]`, you'll get `[60, 70];[80, 90]...`

Comment: Yup lesser code one must have the knowledge of thorough guava libraries for this :). Thanks for late but nicer reply.

Answer (score 0):

The normal approach is to split the string by the delimiting character (`;`) and insert the elements into a sorted set (e.g., [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)).  Then you can simply iterate over the set and join the elements into a string using the delimiter again.  Since you need to sort numerically, you have to implement a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and pass an instance to the `TreeSet` constructor.

The benefit of this approach is that there is no need for an external sort.  The collection will maintain the values in sorted order so you simply iterate over the collection to recover the sorted elements.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args){
          String s="[160,190];[650,790];[901,974];[401,540];[60,90]";
          String[] stringArray = s.split(";");
          Arrays.sort(stringArray,new TokensComparator());
          String newString=Main.join(stringArray,";");
          System.out.print(newString);
      }

    static String join(String[] stringArray, String delimiter) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i<stringArray.length; i++) {
            builder.append(stringArray[i]);
            builder.append(delimiter);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    static class TokensComparator implements Comparator<String> {
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            String token1 = s1.substring(1,s1.length()-1).split(",")[0];
            String token2 = s2.substring(1,s2.length()-1).split(",")[0];
            return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(token1),Integer.parseInt(token2));
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: The method compare(int, int) is undefined for the type Integer , this is a warning in my case

Comment: This method added in 1.7.

Comment: You can use simple if then instead it for java 1.6 and 1.5